# Parsing a city coordinates using regexp in Java

Tags: java, regex

Is there a simple way to parse a line such as

outputting the result in String, double, double using regular expressions?

e.g.

"New York 40.7127°N 74.0059°W " or

"Washington 38° 53' 55.133" N 77° 02' 15.691" W"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and simplest way is to split by space

```
String test = "New York 40.7127°N 74.0059°W ";
String[] splited = test.split("\\s+");
for (String item : splited)
    System.out.println(item);
```

If you want to use regex as you say then first check the beginning for non-digits to get the name

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\D*)");
```

Then this for the numbers

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d|\\.)*");
```

you can get the results like this:

```
while (m2.find())
        System.out.println(m2.group(0));
```

check here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

If you want to get String or double then you simply have to parse the results as such.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is not specifically about the ° character. The regular expression

```
Pattern.compile("([\w ]+) (\d.*\w) (\d.*\w)");
```

will capture the groups in each string as shown:

"Washington 38° 53' 55.133" N 77° 02' 15.691" W"

"New York 40.7127°N 74.0059°W"

will be grouped as

Washington, 38° 53' 55.133" N, 77° 02' 15.691" W

New York, 40.7127°N, 74.0059°W

I suggest that you convert the groups of strings into the format (Double, String, String) outside of the regular expression because of the differing degree formats.